# Why is using(null) a valid case in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement

Could someone please explain to me why the code shown below is valid in C# and executes the call to `Console.WriteLine`?

```
using (null) 
{
   Console.WriteLine ("something is here")
}
```

It compiles into (finally block  is shown). As you can see compiler decides not to execute the `Dispose()` method and jumps to the `endfinally` instruction.

```
IL_0013:  ldnull
IL_0014:  ceq
IL_0016:  stloc.1
IL_0017:  ldloc.1
IL_0018:  brtrue.s   IL_0021 // branches here and decide not to execute Dispose()
IL_001a:  ldnull
IL_001b:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
IL_0020:  nop
IL_0021:  endfinally
```

However, if I run the following code, it will fail with a `NullReferenceException` (which is expected):

```
((IDisposable)null).Dispose();
IL_0023:  ldnull
IL_0024:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
```

Why does the first version compile? Why does the compiler decide not to execute `Dispose()`? Are there any other cases when compiler may decide not to call `Dispose()` in a `using` block?

Comment: hmmm... I'm now very dubious of this post, given Eric's recent blog... is this really a genuine question?

Comment: Isn't this already asked?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522822/c-using-statement-with-a-null-object

Comment: Yea, it seemed contrived to me.

Answer (score 17):

The language spec explicitly states (8.13) that the captured value is tested for null if necessary, i.e. the `finally` is essentially (with caveats around non-nullable types)

```
if(tmp != null) tmp.Dispose();
```

I frequently use this to my advantage, for things that *might* be null, but when they aren't: need disposing. In fact, here's a useful scenario (manually enumerating `IEnumerable`):

```
IEnumerable blah = ...; // note non-generic version
IEnumerator iter = blah.GetEnumerator();
using(iter as IDisposable)
{
    // loop
}
```

as the non-generic version of `IEnumerator` isn't necessarily `IDisposable`, but when it is, should be disposed.

Comment: Thanks for nice trick with *as IDisposable*. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is too clever for my taste :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a natural outcome of the more general case of `using(some_expression)`, where `some_expression` [is allowed to evaluate to `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707399/will-using-work-on-null/707420#707420).

It would have required a special rule to distinguish this case from the more general one.

Answer (score 0):

It will ignore if the Object is null - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Where does it say that in the documentation you linked to? A search for `null` on that page returned 0 hits.

Comment: In the remarks section. if (font1 != null)
      ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();

Comment: > A using statement is translated into three parts: acquisition, usage, and disposal. Usage of the resource is implicitly enclosed in a try statement that includes a finally clause. This finally clause disposes of the resource. If a null resource is acquired, then no call to Dispose is made, and no exception is thrown.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736(v=vs.71).aspx